# How to properly include php files inside wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am creating my first custom wordpress plugin.

I have run into an issue when I try to create a link in an included file to one of the plugin menus in the dashboard.

**Here is my code for the link**

```html
<p><a href="http://localhost/greypower/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add-members">Add a new record</a></p>
```

>

As you may have noticed it is using a full URI.

I have tried using ?page=add-members as the href source and it seems to work.

I am wondering if that is the appropirate method to do this or if there is a more standardized way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to add your page in admin’s menu?

Comment: I have done with the include statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the get_site_url function.

```
<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>
```

So ideally you would link it like:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=add-members">Add a new record</a></p>
```

You can read about it on the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/).